# How to find the maximum number of vertices in a tree with respect to maximum path length and maximum degree value

Tags: graph-theory, trees

Given a tree, find the maximum number of vertices $v$ in that tree using the maximum path length $p$ and a maximum degree that applies to all vertices $d$.

Assuming that I drew my test tree correctly, in the case where the path is no longer than $5$, and the vertex degree can be no higher than $3$, then the maximum number of vertices should be $14$. Is this right? I have tried other values for $p$ and $d$ and drawing the trees for them, but don't see the pattern in the data.

I don't know which formula I can use to derive the maximum number of vertices when $p$ and $d$ are unknown. I would like to know what the formula is, if it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy case is when $p$ is even.  In that case you want $d$ paths coming up from the root (level 0) and each vertex until layer $\frac p2$ has $d-1$ branches upward.  This gives $1+d+(d-1)d +(d-1)^2d +\ldots d(d-1)^ {\frac p2-1}=1+d+d\frac{(d-1)^{\frac p2}-1}{d-2}$

If $p$ is odd, you can have one branch of height $\frac {p+1}2$ and all the other branches can have height $\frac {p-1}2$.  You should be able to follow the above logic to get the expression in that case.